# Every word longer than 3 letter starts with capitalized + first line is Upper case - quick question

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter, uppercase

I got assignment to do first line in upper case and in the rest every word that is 3 or more characters long starts with upper case.

I am testing it in console so its made partly with streamreader/streamwriter, but when it functions well I will correct it.

Problem is that the **Console.WriteLine();** before for loop with it, it makes an empty line after the first line but without it, it does not make 3rd line. The input text looks like this

```
title of text
sssssss ss ssss, ss sssssss
ddddd ddd ddddd dddddd
```

with the WriteLine it ends up like this:

```
TITLE OF TEXT

sssssss ss ssss, ss sssssss
ddddd ddd ddddd dddddd
```

and without:

```
TITLE OF TEXT
Sssssss ss Ssss, ss Sssssss Ddddd Ddd Ddddd Dddddd
```

I think I made it too complicated and got kinda lost so I am looking for the solution to this small problem or also to make this code easier but thats not the point right now.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace priklad_8._4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            firstUpper(@"aaa.txt", @"new.txt");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void firstUpper(String from, String to)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(from);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(to);
            String s;
            int length = 0;
            char[] pole = new char[100];
            char dd = 'A';
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpper());
                    length++;
                }
                else
                {
                    String[] ss = s.Trim(' ').Split(' ');

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ss.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (ss[i].Length >= 3)
                        {
                            String ds = ss[i];
                            char[] das = ds.ToCharArray();

                            Console.Write(Char.ToUpper(das[0]) + ds.Substring(1) + " ");
                            if ((int)dd == 10)
                            {

                                Console.WriteLine();

                            }
                        }
                        else Console.Write(ss[i] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Close();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The wording of your question is confusing me, but since you said you became lost I think it would help to separate your different kinds of logic into methods themselves, and using more descriptive variable names. So start with breaking your code into MakeFirstLineUppercase(), IsWordOverThreeLetters(), MakeWordCapitalized() etc. and then name your variables like `var currentLine = s.Trim()`... `var currentTrimmedLine` etc. Just re-writing your code like this might solve most of your problems.

Comment: Thank you for advice I got the solution from the comment but I will also do this to make it more organized and easier to understand so I dont get lost again later on. @aweyeahdawg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to leave everything else as it is, just instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpper());
```

use this:

```
Console.Write(s.ToUpper())
```

Comment: Oh thank you, so simple but I was really lost in the code. I will also rewrite the code and make it more organized to understand it better as @aweyeagdawg mentioned

Comment: Just to give you more explaination of why: in the case where it was the first line, you were reaching the ```Console.Writeline(s.ToUpper())``` in your if. And second iteration, you were reaching the ```Console.Writeline()``` just at the beginning of your else. That's why you had 2 new lines. Yes refactor your code. and feel free to use breakpoints, as I think it would have helped you find this

Comment: Indeed do that. Some tips: remove the redundant stuff; maybe use `bool` to check whether it's the first line, instead of `int`; don't convert to `char` array, you can directly access string's characters with `[ ]` operator: `Char.ToUpper(ds[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a cleaner way to get there:

```
using (var input = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
{
    var currentLine = 0;
    while (!input.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = input.ReadLine() ?? "";
        if (++currentLine == 1)
        {
            // first line is upper case
            Console.WriteLine(line.ToUpper());
        }
        else
        {
            // Every word longer than 3 letter starts with capitalized
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"\w{3,}", 
                (match) => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                    .TextInfo.ToTitleCase(match.Value.ToLower())));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Cleaner way to get there making use of File.ReadAllLines, and File.WriteAllLines

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");
    var newLines = new string[lines.Count()];

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            newLines[i] = lines[i].ToUpper();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var word in lines[i].Split(' '))
            {
                newLines[i] += string.Format("{0} ", word.Length >= 3 ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word) : word);
            }
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines("newText.txt", newLines);
}
```

And i mean, if you wanted a very unclean looking one liner because i was bored.. You could do this.

```
static void Run(string fromFile, string toFile)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(toFile, File.ReadAllLines(fromFile).Select((line, index) => index == 0 ? line.ToUpper() : Regex.Replace(line, @"\w{3,}", (match) => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(match.Value))));
}
```